# How to get the entire text of a Window in a Windows application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, text, window

I have a Windows app(Windows Form Application). I need run a automation to grab all the text in the current window, including window tiles, and all the text of all the elements inside the window.

I tried using SendMessage and GetWindowText, it only returns the window tile, but I need to get the text inside the window too.

Is there a method which can grab all text in the window?
Or do I need to loop through all elements, and get the text? and how to do it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you're doing that?

Comment: You can iterate through all the controls and try accessing their text property dynamically. But i don't know how you will be able to access every control's text property

Comment: If you're trying to automate unit tests, you'd be better off just testing manually as interfaces change too often and have too many non-testable elements for unit testing to be feasible.

Comment: The reason I'm doing it is for localization purpose, to get the text in different locales.

Comment: Are you trying to do this to your own window, or to that of a third party app? (My answer assumes the latter.)

Comment: yes Richard, on that of a third party app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a method which can grab all text in the window?

No, or rather "not without knowing how the text is rendered".

If the Window contains other controls (eg. labels) then you need to enumerate those controls and get their text.

If the text is being drawn directly onto the surface of the window (eg. in `WM_PAINT` handler) then it is just a bitmap being displayed (the text has been lost) and there is no easy way to recover it if there is nothing provided by the application (OCR is another option).

Comment: Thank you for your response, you mentioned "If the Window contains other controls (eg. labels) then you need to enumerate those controls and get their text. " Is there a way to enumerate all existing controls under the window handler, or I need know what the exact controls are?

Comment: @user1488025 Child controls can be enumerated (SPY++ does it), but I'm not sure how. Apply some search-fu.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to traverse all elements on the form and get their text values separately.

This recursive function will return a string list of all the text values of the control you specify and all its child controls.

```
private List<string> getStrings(Control control)
{
    List<string> retval = new List<string>();
    if (control.Text != "")
        retval.Add(control.Text);

    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        retval.AddRange(getStrings(child));

    return retval;
}
```

So if you call this from your main form, you'd call it like this:
`List<string> allStrings = getStrings(this);`

Take note though that this function only returns the text values of all the controls on the form, and following their child controls recursively. Some controls (like ListBox) for instance may have a whole list of text values inside which will not be returned by this function. To do that you may have to extend the function somewhat to test for the type of control and return its contents specifically if applicable.

Comment: Hi Dewald, Thank you for your quick response, I only get the windowhandle of the main window, the windowhandle is not null, but if I use the method to try to get the control by using Control.FromHandle(hwnd), the Control is always null. do I use the correct method?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Where are you getting the handle of the control from? If you call `Control.FromHandle(hwnd)` and it returns **null** then I suspect your handle is not correct. Maybe you should post your code so we can have a look.

Comment: I can use the same windowhandle  to run GetWindowText and get the returned window title. sorry, I forgot to mention: the app is a 3rd party app, I need to run an automation to access to the app and grab the text.